# Taking continuous input from user in C

Tags: c, input, terminal, user-input

I am working on a project where I have to take input from a user in the terminal in c until they input quit then I end the program. I realized I cant do this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>    

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char *i;
    while(1){
        scanf("%s", i);

        /*do my program here*/
        myMethod(i);

    }

}
```

So my question is how can I go about taking this coninuous user input? Can I do it with loops or what else can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to allocate space for the string you are reading, this is normally done with a `char` array with the size of a macro. `char i[BUFFER_SIZE]` Then you read data into your buffer,[`fgets`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fgets&sektion=3) might be better than [`scanf`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=scanf&sektion=3) for that. Finally you check your exit case, a [`strcmp`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strcmp&sektion=3) with `"quit"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE BUFSIZ /* or some other number */

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    char i[BUFFER_SIZE];
    fgets(i, BUFSIZ, stdin);
    while (strcmp(i, "quit\n") != 0) {
        myMethod(i);
        fgets(i, BUFSIZ, stdin);
    }
}
```

Strings obtained with [`fgets`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fgets&sektion=3) are gurenteed null terminated

Comment: Ok awesome this is working just one problem though when I type quit it doesn't exit the program any idea why?

Comment: Because `fgets()` also writes the newline character.

Comment: Actually just got it didn't realize that the fgets puts a \n at the end of the input string so just add \n to the end of the strcmp line and it works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

scanf() will return number of elements successfully read I will make use of it like below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
   int a[20];
   int i=0;
   printf("Keep entering numbers and when you are done press some character\n");
   while((scanf("%d",&a[i])) == 1)
   {   
      printf("%d\n",a[i]);
      i++;
   }   

   printf("User has ended giving inputs\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a do while loop:

```
do
{
    // prompts the user 
}
while (valueGiven != "quit");
```

Comment: `!=` cannot be used on arrays (which `"quit"` is)

Comment: yes I tried this with strcmp however and I am getting a segfault after scanf.

Comment: That'll happen when you try to stuff input into no memory.

Answer (score -1):

```
using do-while loop. 

   char *i = null;
   char ch = 'a';/
   do{
    scanf("%s", &i);

    /*do my program here*/
    myMethod(i);
    printf("Do you want to continues.. y/n");
    ch =  getchar();

    }while(ch != 'q');
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_do_while_loop.htm

Comment: why a negative vote?

Comment: For writing an answer that'll lead to an immediate segmentation fault, at least if it didn't contain a syntax error?

Comment: Code is right now paul  hopefully?

Comment: No, you actually made it worse.

Comment: It's not my answer, is it?

Comment: I know this. I just want to correct myself. You have mentioned the issue in code. I have tried to remove it. but did not succeed. that why i have said to you please update it.